# What is required to get a Connected App whitelisted?

Tags: connected-apps, whitelisting

[This article](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm#dev_packages_api_access) mentions whitelisting a connected app, but I have not been able to find any resources on how to begin the whitelisting process, and what is required of my application to be successfully whitelisted. Is the security review part of the whitelisting process? How long does the whitelisting process take? What else do you know about whitelisting? (because I have found very little about it online thus far).

It is my understanding that our connected app be whitelisted before Group Edition and Professional Edition SF orgs can install our connected app (and gain REST API access)

Update: [here is a precursor](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm#security_review) to the original article. Based on the url anchor, whitelisting is the same as the security review process, but I would like something a little more concrete than an url anchor.

Another Update: [This article](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_rest_api_access.htm) is slightly more helpful.

Comment: Did you ever find any additional resources or get additional information? I too am unable to find much on whitelisted apps.

Answer (score 1):

The prerequisite to allow API access for a GE/PE org is a managed package that successfully passed security review.

Given that you need to create a Support Case via the Partner Portal and request the appropriate permissions for the connected app contained in the managed package.

The 'appropriate permissions' depend on type of API you want to consume; for example the REST API requires the connected app to get whitelisted while other APIs require a special API token you need to request via the support case.

All details are described here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm